# extract columns that don't have a header or name in R

Tags: r

I need to extract the columns from a dataset without header names.

I have a ~10000 x 3 data set and I need to plot the first column against the second two.

I know how to do it when the columns have names ~ `plot(data$V1, data$V2)` but in this case they do not. How do I access each column individually when they do not have names?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not give them sensible names?

```
names(data)=c("This","That","Other")
plot(data$This,data$That)
```

That's a better solution than using the column number, since names are meaningful and if your data changes to have a different number of columns your code may break in several places. Give your data the correct names and as long as you always refer to `data$This` then your code will work.

Answer (score 6):

I usually select columns by their position in the matrix/data frame.

e.g.

`dataset[,4]` to select the 4th column.

The 1st number in brackets refers to rows, the second to columns. Here, I didn't use a "1st number" so all rows of column 4 are selected, i.e., the whole column.

This is easy to remember since it stems from matrix calculations. E.g., a 4x3 dimensional matrix has 4 rows and 3 columns. Thus when I want to select the 1st row of the third column, I could do something like `matrix[1,3]`